# Office 365 Sharepoint Library files missing and not seen in recycle bin too

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-library

Office 365 SharePoint Files missing from the document library looked in recycle bin too did not find the document.Is there anything that we can do to restore the documents that are missing?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint online has two recycle bins. When you delete an item from list or library the item goes to the recycle bin. When you delete the item from the recycle bin it goes to the Second stage recycle bin. When you delete it from the second stage recycle bin it is definitely deleted and cannot be restored.

Recycle bin:

```
subsiteurl/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx?view=5
```

Second stage recycle bin:

```
subsiteurl/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx?view=13
```

[This article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-deleted-items-from-the-site-collection-recycle-bin-5fa924ee-16d7-487b-9a0a-021b9062d14b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) contains useful info about restoring the deleted items.

If you don't see your deleted documents in neither of the mentioned recycle bins then it is definitely deleted.

**EDIT**: You need to be the site collection administrator in order to be able to open the second stage recycle bin (as Zach Koehne stated in the comment).

Comment: You'll need to be the site collection admin or you won't be able to get to the second stage bin.